# jQuery tool tip - Title line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseevent, jquery-hover

I'm using this jQuery plugin to make tool tips when hover over text and pictures
http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/jquery/simple-tooltip/index.html

The problem is i can't figure out how to make line breaks within the title tag.

I have looked at other people asking the same questing, so i have already tried the following:

```
<br />
\n
&#13;


<a title='Tool
Tip
On
New
Line'>link with tip</a>
```

But none of the above work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're probably running this code (from the site linked in your question):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Tooltip only Text
    $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
            // Hover over code
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
            $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
            .text(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
            // Hover out code
            $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
            $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
            var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
            var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
            $('.tooltip')
            .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
    });
});
```

Note that it uses `$('<p class="tooltip"></p>').text(title)`. If you change that to `.html(title)`, you should be able to use `<br>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/tugpM/